# plv8 binaries copied to respective folders but error in loading libaries as specified procedure not found

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, plv8

> ERROR: could not load library "C:/POSTGR~1/pg94/../pg94/lib/postgresql/plv8.dll": The specified procedure could not be found.
>   SQL state: XX000

I have installed postgres 9.4.15, and want to install plv8 1.4.3.
I have copied the binary files from 
http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/341-PLV8-binaries-for-PostgreSQL-9.4-windows-both-32-bit-and-64-bit.html

All 64 bit version. Error displayed after running query: CREATE EXTENSION plv8;

Comment: I'd use the *dependency walker* or a similar tool to see what dependencies the DLL has. Maybe some required software is missing? Maybe something is not on your `PATH`?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @laurenzAlbe, However, the  file for plv8  has a bin, lib and share folders which are to be copied in respective folders of postgres, concluding the only dependency for dll file

Comment: Are you certain? PL/v8 should be linked with the v8 shared library, unless that has been linked into it statically.

Comment: Not so certain, cause it worked perfectly for the postgres 10.6 version with plv8 1.4.10 version.

Comment: However, issue was immediately resolved with another version of postgresql 9.4.21

Comment: Probably a library version mismatch then. I wouldn't want to use an operating system without library versioning...